# Longest Palindrome Substring: Where is the dynamic programming?

Tags: python, interview-questions, palindrome, dynamic-programming

In this [LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/), Longest Palindromic Substring, it is listed under Dynamic Programming for Google interview preparation. My understanding of dynamic programming is roughly "recursion + memoization + guessing." In the Python solution to this answer below it is not clear to me where the dynamic programming is if it exists at all. This is [Approach 4](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/solution/) under solutions (translated from Java to Python). Approach 3 references dynamic programming but no solution is given.

Is there any dynamic programming going on here? Or is this just a solution to solve the problem in O(1) space, where the dynamic programming solution requires O(n^2) space?

This algorithm technically has a time complexity of O(n^2) right? Is this the best we could reasonably be expected to do in an interview?

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        res = ""
        for i in range(len(s)):
            # odd case, like "aba"
            tmp = self.helper(s, i, i)
            if len(tmp) > len(res):
                res = tmp
            # even case, like "abba"
            tmp = self.helper(s, i, i+1)
            if len(tmp) > len(res):
                res = tmp
        return res

    # get the longest palindrome, l, r are the middle indexes   
    # from inner to outer
    def helper(self, s, l, r):
        while l >= 0 and r < len(s) and s[l] == s[r]:
            l -= 1; r += 1
        return s[l+1:r]
```

Comment: Which website should this be included on?

Comment: I suggest [cs.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=lps)